# How to get name of specific Jlabel, created dynamically from values in resultset. Using JPop menu item?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am creating a restaurant menu, I am using values from resultSet to create JLabel for each entry dynamically. Now I want to get an ID of specific Jlabel using JPopupMenu, menu item. I have added ActionListener on menu item but its returning IDs of all Jlabel instead of that specific Jlabel. Can someone please help me out. I have attached the code below.

```
private void fillPanel() {

Integer id;

MenuDAOImpl menuDAOImpl = new MenuDAOImpl();

resultSet = menuDAOImpl.getAllMenuItems();


    try {
            while(resultSet.next()){

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(resultSet.getString("item_img"));
                 JLabel label = new JLabel(img);
                 label.setText(resultSet.getString("item_name"));
                 label.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 11));
                 label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                 label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
                 id = resultSet.getInt("item_id");
                 label.setName(id.toString());
                 label.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(label.getName());
          }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {
        if (evt.isPopupTrigger()){          
            JLabel source = (JLabel)evt.getSource();
            menuItemPopup.show(evt.getComponent(), evt.getX(), evt.getY());
               } 

             }

            }); 

          // This is the menu item in JpopupMenu
 // This method below is returning Id of every Jlabel created.
            updateMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ 
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                     System.out.println(label.getName());
                 }


             });
            menuItem.add(label);
            }  

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MenuFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


        menuItem.revalidate();
        menuItem.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an improved version of a [previously posted question].  Please make your code [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically creating objects, then you need to create generic listeners. These listeners should be created outside the loop and shared by all components you create.

Also, a JPopuMenu is designed to be used with JMenuItmes. A JMenuItem support icons and you add an ActionListener to the menu item to handle the mouse click of the item.

So a generic listener would look something like:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JMenuItem menuItem = (JMenuItem)e.getSource();
        System.out.println( menuItem.getName() );
    }
}
```

You create the listener before you start your looping code.

Then in your looping code you do something like:

```
while(resultSet.next())
{
    JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(...);
    ...
    Integer id = resultSet.getInt("item_id");
    menuItem.setName(id.toString());
    menuItem.addActionListener( al );
}
```

Comment: I tried it, its returning null and for every label created.

Comment: "I tried it " - please post an updated [mcve] of your code.